# NameError: name of the class not defined inside the class itself - python

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class ClassProperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()

def coord(cls, c):
    if cls.dimension <= 2:
        return c
    else:
        return c + [0]*(cls.dimension-2)

class Basis_NonI(object):

    @ClassProperty
    @classmethod
    def zerocoord(cls):
        return coord(cls, [0,0])   
        
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        pass

class Basis_D(Basis_NonI):
    dimension = 2
    proj_matrix = np.array([Basis_D.zerocoord, Basis_D.zerocoord])
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        super(Basis_D, self).__init__(Basis_D.dimension)
```

where basically I want `dimension` and `proj_matrix`to be class attributes of `Basis_D`.

When I run it, the following error is given:

> proj_matrix = np.array([Basis_D.zerocoord, Basis_D.zerocoord])
>
> NameError: name 'Basis_D' is not defined

--

What I don't understand is that I can use Basis_D.dimension in the `init`, so why does it not recongise the name `Basis_D` when I use it to define `proj_matrix`?

Comment: I don't think `Basis_D` is defined when the line `proj_matrix = np.array([Basis_D.zerocoord, Basis_D.zerocoord])` is run. Since `zerocoord` is a member of the inherited class, why not use `Basis_NonI.zerocoord`?

Comment: Because `Basis_NonI` does not have an attribute `dimension`. How do you knwo when `Basis_D` is defined?

Comment: It's defined after the whole `class` statement has been executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` is an executable statement. When the module is first imported (for a given process), all the code at the top-level of the `class` statement is executed, all names defined that way are collected into a dict, then the `class` object is created with this dict, and finally bound to the class name. IOW, at this point:

```
class Basis_D(Basis_NonI):
   dimension = 2
   # HERE
   proj_matrix = np.array([Basis_D.zerocoord, Basis_D.zerocoord])
```

the class has not yet been created nor bound to the name `Basis_D`.

Now by the time `__init__` is called, the class has already been created and bound to the module-level name `Basis_D`, so the name can be resolved.

FWIW, you shouldn't directly reference `Basis_D` in your methods, but `type(self)`  (or even `self` - if a name is not resolved as an instance attribute, it's looked up on the class).

Also, why do you insist on using class attributes ? Do you understand that your `project_matrix` array will be shared amongst all instances of `Basis_D` ?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced `Basid_D.zerocoord` by `self.zerocoord` and it still complains that `self is not defined`. I thought that class attributes are created just once per class, whereas instance attributes are created each time I make an instance. Stuff like `dimension` and `proj_matrix`  are fixed withih the class, as in they will never change, so I wanted to save "memory"

Comment: Basically I want to avoid creating `proj_matrix` each time I make an instance of the class.#

Comment: Why? Do you really understand the implications of making it a class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Basis_D gets created once all the statements inside it are executed and reaches the end.
You can check that using globals() dictionary.

```
class Basis_D(Basis_NonI):
dimension = 2
print('Basis_D got created?:',bool(globals().get('Basis_D')))
#proj_matrix = np.array([Basis_D.zerocoord, Basis_D.zerocoord])
def __init__(self, dimension):
    super(Basis_D, self).__init__(Basis_D.dimension)

print('Basis_D got created?:',bool(globals().get('Basis_D')))

=================== RESTART: D:/PythonWorkspace/sometry.py ===================
Basis_D got created?: False
Basis_D got created?: True
```