# NameError in Class being its own controller when declaring static values

Tags: python, class, object, object-oriented-analysis

I want a class to be its own controller and initiate a few default values, this way :

```
class Foo:
    FOOS = [Foo(5), Foo(3), Foo(4)]

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

But I get a `NameError` exception :

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 2, in Foo
    FOOS = [Foo(5), Foo(3), Foo(4)]
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

Question : **What is the correct Pythonic way of having a class being it's own controller ?**

Sidenote : I can't believe I'm the first one to have this problem. If it's a duplicate, I haven't found it.

EDIT : See the comment to see why I think it's not a duplicate of the linked question, I don't want to pollute my question with explanations about it.

Comment: When exactly should the FOOS be declared? When making a new instance of this class? When starting the program? Elsewhen?

Comment: @DWuest When starting the program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name of the class not defined inside the class itself - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894368/nameerror-name-of-the-class-not-defined-inside-the-class-itself-python)

Comment: I think it's related, but my question is not exactly a duplicate, or brings something to the site. First I do only have one class in my example, against 3 in the linked thread.
If the problem is the same (which I feel like it's not the case), my solution should be way more clearer for anyone encountering the same difficulty.
As well, I'm asking for a specific way of making a class being it's own controller, which makes my question more oriented toward POO practices in Python rather than just solving an exception.
I could detail what I mean by "Pythonic" if you ask me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a static method on the class which initializes the values you want that must be called before instantiating any instances of the class. This can be enforced by raising an error if attempted:

```
class Foo:
    FOOS = []
    init = False

    def __init__(self, bar):
        if not Foo.init:
            pass # raise some error
        self.bar = bar

    @staticmethod    
    def initialise():
        if not Foo.init:
            Foo.init = True
            Foo.FOOS = [Foo(5), Foo(3), Foo(4)]

Foo.initialise()
thing = Foo(2)
```

Comment: This answer works, I don't like too much having to structure my code like that, but if it's how it's done in Python then I guess it's ok.
I'll wait a bit to see if anyone post another solution that I like more if not I'll validate yours. Thanks !

Comment: What you want is *similar* but not exactly the Singleton designed pattern, in that you have a class keeping track of it's own instantiation. Maybe a search of such implementations in python might give you inspiration for something alternative, but I quite like the transparency in what I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class Foo:
    pass

Foo.FOOS = [ Foo(), Foo() ]
```