# What is the best practice for class properties of the same type in python?

Tags: python, class

As a beginner in python, it's not clear to me how to add class vars of the same type it's contained in.

```
class Resolution:
    def __init__(self, width = 0, height = 0):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    # This works, but is it the recommended approach?
    @classmethod
    def sd(cls):
        return cls(640, 480)

    @classmethod
    def hd(cls):
        return cls(1280, 720)
```

Edit:

Removed part which was a duplicate question.

Using @MichaelButscher's approach of adding `Resolution.SD = Resolution(640, 480)` after the class definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name of the class not defined inside the class itself - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894368/nameerror-name-of-the-class-not-defined-inside-the-class-itself-python)

Comment: @Reznik thanks, that explains why it doesn't work, but I'm still interested if there is a more succinct implementation.

Comment: Consider make those classmethod as `property`, more then that i dont think there is another solution

Comment: You can add it after class definition: `Resolution.SD = Resolution(640, 480)`

Comment: @MichaelButscher this is what I was looking for thank you!